# How I set the default position of a NSScroll view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsview, nsscrollview

I have a trouble with a NSScrollview in my aplication because it always start at the bottom of the window. How could make it start in the top?

Comment: You like to scroll NSScrollView programmatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSPoint pointToScrollTo = NSMakePoint (  ,  );  // Any point you like.
[[scrollView contentView] scrollToPoint: pointToScrollTo];
[scrollView reflectScrolledClipView: [scrollView contentView]];
```

Comment: This works well in swift too, adapted slightly:                     scrollView!.documentView = toolsView
                var scrollLocation = NSPoint(x: 0, y: toolsView.frame.size.height - leftScrollView!.contentView.frame.size.height)
                leftScrollView!.contentView.scrollToPoint(scrollLocation)
                leftScrollView!.reflectScrolledClipView(leftScrollView!.contentView)

Answer (score 4):

A solution is given in the Scroll View Programming Guide, [Scrolling to a Specific Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003463-SW2). You can use [`-[NSView scrollPoint:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-BBCBEGBH) to set the clip view's origin.

```
// A controller which has an outlet to the scroll view
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    // Not checking for flipped document view. See sample code.
    // New origin should be 
    // (documentView.frame.y + documentView.frame.height) - clipView.bounds.height
    NSPoint newOrigin = NSMakePoint(0, NSMaxY([[scrollView documentView] frame]) -
                                           [[scrollView contentView] bounds].size.height);
    [[scrollView documentView] scrollPoint:newOrigin];
}
```

Comment: It works for me but :     `NSPoint newOrigin = NSMakePoint(0, NSMaxY([[scrollView documentView] frame]) - [[scrollView contentView] bounds].size.height);
    [[scrollView documentView] scrollPoint:newOrigin];``

Answer (score 3):

If you have a custom NSView subclass inside the NSScrollView, try overriding `isFlipped`:

```
- (BOOL)isFlipped
{
    return YES;
}
```

This puts the view's origin at the top, which should make the NSScrollView do what you want.

However, it will also flip the coordinates of everything inside your view.